# Why is the jQuery FileTree showing files when not set to?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [jqueryfiletree plugin](https://github.com/jqueryfiletree/jqueryfiletree), and it seems established and fairly smooth, but I have some issues:

Despite the options being set as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $("#sourceFileTree").fileTree({
        onlyFolders: true,
        root: "C%3a%5cProjects%5cBMW%5cCode%5cFileTransfers.Web",
        script: "/FileTree/Tree",
        multiFolder: false,
        multiSelect: false,
        preventLinkAction: true
    });
});
```

1. `onlyFolders` seems to be ignored, and any folder opened also shows files it contains.
2. The same goes for `multiSelect: false`. While I can "select" (highlight it in bold) only one file at a time, I can still check as many folder and file checkboxes as I want.
3. Only `multiFolder: false` seems to work as documented, but I don't know if it's because that's a default behaviour anyway.

What am I doing wrong if I want to configure this widget to allow the user to select only one folder?

Comment: What connector are you using? Given the asp.net-mvc tag, I assume you're not using the default connector (jqueryFileTree.php).    The ASP connectors (from here: https://github.com/jqueryfiletree/jqueryfiletree/tree/master/dist/connectors/Asp.Net-MVC)  don't seem to reference the options you are using.

Comment: I'm using a custom connector through ASP.NET MVC Core. I have an action method that retunes the expected HTML.

Comment: OK, the point is, the connector is the one that needs to filter the files/directories.  If you look at the code for PHP connector, you'll see that it filters the files:  if( is_dir($postDir . $file) && (!$onlyFiles || $onlyFolders) )... I don't see anything similar in the ASP connector.

Comment: @BumptiousQBangwhistle I said I'm using a custom connector, so you can't see anything on it. It's just a simple MVC controller with a `roots` action that gets called by the widget, and a 'files' action that also gets called.

Comment: @BumptiousQBangwhistle Sorry, I didn't say I'm using a custom connector. Now you know.

Comment: I understand.  My point is, it is the Connector that handles the options you are using.  Your custom connector needs to identify the state of the posted variables and handle files/directories accordingly.

Comment: What  @BumptiousQBangwhistle is saying is that those options don't do anything on the client/UI side.  They are passed as some type of parameter to your custom connector.  In your custom connection, *you* need to check those parameter values and filter your returned HTML accordingly.  This is not an issue with implementing the jQuery plugin on the front end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The connector (yes, yours is custom) is what performs the filtering on the results.  If you are not looking for / using the passed parameters from the jQuery plugin, then the results will not be what you expect.  From the link someone posted above (https://github.com/jqueryfiletree/jqueryfiletree/blob/master/dist/connectors/Asp.Net-MVC/FileTreeController.cs) and the PHP version which seems to use the applicable options (https://github.com/jqueryfiletree/jqueryfiletree/blob/master/dist/connectors/jqueryFileTree.php), we can update this just a bit to return a better result set.

*Note* - we do not have insight into your files, so this is a very freshman example using some boilerplate code.  Also, I know your answer is about .NET core, but the logic should still hold true even if the syntax is not exactly the same between 4.6 and Core

```
[HttpPost]
//notice the added additional params to the expected request variables
//these appear to match the names of the jQuery options
public virtual ActionResult GetFiles(string dir, bool multiSelect, 
    bool onlyFolders, bool onlyFiles)
{
    const string baseDir = @"/App_Data/userfiles/";

    dir = Server.UrlDecode(dir);
    string realDir = Server.MapPath(baseDir + dir);

    //validate to not go above basedir
    if (! realDir.StartsWith(Server.MapPath(baseDir)))
    {
        realDir = Server.MapPath(baseDir);
        dir = "/";
    }

    List<FileTreeViewModel> files = new List<FileTreeViewModel>();

    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(realDir);

    foreach (DirectoryInfo dc in di.GetDirectories())
    {                
        files.Add(new FileTreeViewModel() { Name = dc.Name, Path = String.Format("{0}{1}\\", dir, dc.Name), IsDirectory = true });
    }

    foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
    {
        files.Add(new FileTreeViewModel() { Name = fi.Name, Ext = fi.Extension.Substring(1).ToLower(), Path = dir+fi.Name, IsDirectory = false });
    }
    //lets filter some results using the properties of 
    //the `FileTreeViewModel()` class
    //I have no idea how you are wanting to use multiSelect, so 
    //it has been left out of this example.
    if(onlyFolders){
        files = files.Where(x=>x.IsDirectory).ToList();
    }
    if(onlyFiles){
        files = files.Where(x=>!x.IsDirectory).ToList();
    }
    return PartialView(files);
}
```